# How should my local server communicate with an EC2 server?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js server running on ec2. I'd like for that server to automatically push data to another node.js server that is running on my laptop.

What is the best way to do something like this?

Comment: Is your laptop publicly accessible already or is there a firewall that it must go through?

Comment: Right, it's not publicly accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a service like [showoff.io](https://showoff.io/) to create an entry point to access your local laptop, or you could just create an SSH tunnel by running this command on your laptop:

```
ssh -R port:localhost:remoteport ec2-host
```

That will allow `port` on the loopback interface of your EC2 server to connect to `remoteport` on your laptop.

Then just modify your code to connect to the node.js program running on your laptop via the IP of `127.0.0.1` and port of `port`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the EC2 node.js call a function from the local node.js, and pass the data as variables